# Why json array size dynamically increase in java using Json Simple API?

Tags: java, android

in the first image the json array size is 10. After getting 10 object from the json array size dynamically change to 20.?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HpDD.png**strong text**

How to solve thus problem ? I want to get all the array object at once.

Comment: you are not clearing array before it is fill in for loop. so please clear array before for loop. I think the 20 data are repeated

Comment: Please post your code in the question - do not link your code off-site :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not clearing your `documentArray`. It is adding again and again. So write these lines before your `for` `loop`

```
if (documentArray == null)
     documentArray = new JSONArray();
else 
    documentArray.clear();

for()// your for loop here
```